# Perl MySQL INSERT error

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I'm trying to parse a few references from a file and load them into a MySQL table, but I keep on getting this error everytime I run the script

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Njuguna, M.I., Yusuf, J. A., Akama, V.,2013,Animal husbandry in the developed w' at line 1 at manuscripts3.pl line 51, <$fh> line 1.
```

Uncaught exception from user code

See my code below.

I'm at my wits end. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use DBI;

my $driver   = "mysql";
my $database = "test";
my $user     = "root";
my $password = "";

my $dbh      = DBI->connect(
  "DBI:$driver:$database",
  $user,
  $password, {
    RaiseError => 1,
    PrintError => 1,
    AutoCommit => 0,
  }
) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $file = "/var/www/manuscripts.txt";

open my $fh, "<", $file;
my @manuscripts;

while (my $lines = <$fh>) {
  $lines =~ s/\, \(/\t/g;
  $lines =~ s/\) \“/\t/g;
  $lines =~ s/\” /\t/g;

  my ($authors, $year, $title, $journal) = split(/\t/, $lines);

  push @manuscripts, {
    authors => $authors,
    year    => $year,
    title   => $title,
    journal => $journal
  };

  #print "$title\n";
  my $sql = "insert into manuscript($authors,$year,$title,$journal) values (?,?,?,?)";
  $dbh->commit();
  my $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($authors, $year, $title, $journal);

  # disconnect from the MySQL database
  $dbh->disconnect();
}

#print $manuscripts[0][2];
```

text file:

```
Kamau, M.A., Njuguna, M.I., Yusuf, J. A., Akama, V., (2013) “Animal husbandry in the developed world” Journal of Hospital Infenction
Kamau, M.A., Njuguna, M.I., Yusuf, J. A., Akama, V., (2013) “Agriculture and global warming” PLOS Medicine Kamau, M.A., Njuguna,
M.I., Yusuf, J. A., Akama, V., (2013) “Rotational farming as a business” The Journal of Infectious Diseases
```

Comment: this is the textfile

Comment: Kamau, M.A., Njuguna, M.I., Yusuf, J. A., Akama, V., (2013) “Animal husbandry in the developed world” Journal of Hospital Infenction
Kamau, M.A., Njuguna, M.I., Yusuf, J. A., Akama, V., (2013) “Agriculture and global warming” PLOS Medicine
Kamau, M.A., Njuguna, M.I., Yusuf, J. A., Akama, V., (2013) “Rotational farming as a business” The Journal of Infectious Diseases

Comment: Put that *in the question*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use `$stmt->bind_param();` to bind the parameter and use `$stmt->execute()` without parameter

```
my $sql = "insert into manuscript(authors,year,title,journal) 
values (?,?,?,?)";

my $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(1,$authors);
$stmt->bind_param(2,$year);
$stmt->bind_param(3,$title);
$stmt->bind_param(4,$journal);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Using the variables twice - one time in the `$sql` and another time with the bind is the error. Within the SQL there should be the column names used, not the values themselves.

Comment: Thanks Jens and @dgw....the script runs but somehow the data is not inserted to the desired table...sorry for being such a pain

Answer (score 7):

The problem is here:

```
my $sql = "insert into manuscript($authors,$year,$title,$journal) 
values (?,?,?,?)";
```

You are putting the **contents** of the variables as the field names.  I assume you mean:

```
my $sql = "insert into manuscript(authors,year,title,journal) 
values (?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Thanks TobyLL the error is now gone...but the data is not being inserted into table

Comment: Youe have put `AutoCommit => 0` on your connection.  You are then trying to do a `$dbh->commit()` BEFORE you actually run the SQL.  Try moving that to after the `$stmt->execute()`